# Racket run thread for fixed amount of time

Tags: timeout, racket

I'd like to run an expression in racket speculatively, hoping for (but not particularly expecting) a result. My code has a hard time limit. Is there an easy way to run some racket code for a few seconds, then reliably kill it and execute fallback code before the deadline hits?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, an easy way to do this is using the [engine](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/engine.html) library. For example:

```
#lang racket

(require racket/engine)

(define e (engine
           (λ (_)
             ;; just keep printing every second
             (let loop ()
               (displayln "hi")
               (sleep 1)
               (loop)))))

;; run only for 2 seconds
(engine-run 2000 e)
```

Instead of specifying a time, you can also specify an [event](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sync.html) object so that the thread stops running when the event triggers.

Comment: Aren't we cute with the simultaneously-posted answers? :)  Seriously, I didn't even _know_ about `racket/engine`, that's neat.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a "worker" thread to do the work, and another "watcher" thread to kill the worker.

This is described in the [More: Systems Programming](http://docs.racket-lang.org/more/#%28part._.Terminating_.Connections%29) section of the docs.

The simplest, first cut may be sufficient for your calculation:

```
(define (accept-and-handle listener)
  (define-values (in out) (tcp-accept listener))
  (define t (thread
              (lambda ()
                (handle in out)
                (close-input-port in)
                (close-output-port out))))
  ; Watcher thread:
  (thread (lambda ()
            (sleep 10)
            (kill-thread t))))
```

However if you're dealing with other resources read on to learn about custodians.

Comment: With this method, what's the best way to return the result of the first thread up to the main thread? (thread-send) seems a bit ungainly, all I want is something like (thread-wait t) that blocks on t and returns the result. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Good point. You could try a [`channel`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/channel.html) -- have the worker `channel-put` a normal result, have the watcher `channel-put` a timeout result, and have the main thread do `channel-get` to wait for whichever comes first.